# Is there a way to securely lockdown a website to an Iphone?

Tags: authentication, iphone, identity-management

So with a typical website, perhaps the fastest and most effective (arguably) way to secure the site is to add a simple .htaccess and restrict by ip addresses:

```
.htaccess
DENY from ALL
ALLOW from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

but I want to access my website via an approved iphone. Is there an equivalent way to do something like the .htaccess and add each approved device? I doubt the logic will be in an .htaccess file but the end goal is to have a secure device (iphone) that is pre-authenticated to my site without every having the end user enter a site-specific password.

A partial example of this would be how Apple assigns provisioning certificates to a developer's Iphone so that only that developer may run an app that is not released yet.

Once again, I am looking for a solution that **never** asks for a password (at least not from my website).

Answer (score 2):

You can use Apache's [mod_ssl](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html) to [authenticate against client certificates](http://wiki.cacert.org/ApacheServerClientCertificateAuthentication).

The example is from cacert.org, but you can create your own CA to accomplish the same goal.

Comment: I'll look into this...